# What does float *a[]; declare in c?

Tags: c

Suppose float *a[]; is declared in the main method n c. I'm trying to learn about pointers and understand what the above means.

I'm guessing it declares a pointer to the first element of that array a[].
But a[] doesn't have any elements..
I am really confused.

Thanks anyone who helps.

Comment: Can you show this in the context of a semi-complete program?

Comment: @bruno How would a "pointer to an array of float" look?

Comment: `float *a[];` in `main` is a syntax error. So your question makes no sense. Please provide a [mcve] that actually compiles.

Comment: If this is the only definition of `a`, then it is illegal.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because since it won't even compile, it's pointless to discuss what it means.

Comment: Thanks. So it produces syntax error because we basically want to point to nothing?

Comment: It produces syntax error because it is not a valid syntax

Comment: The error message from the compiler is: *"definition of variable with array type needs an explicit size or an initializer"*

Comment: [An array of pointer to float](https://cdecl.org/?q=float+*a%5B%5D%3B).

Comment: Was the code exactly `float *a[];`, or was it `extern float *a[];` or `float *a[] = { stuff }`?

Answer (score 6):

When declaring a variable, it's not valid code without an array size.

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:2:11: error: array size missing in ‘a’
    float *a[];
```

With an array size, it creates an array of pointers.

Test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   printf("float:           %zu\n", sizeof(float));
   printf("pointer:         %zu\n", sizeof(void*));

   float *a[100];
   printf("float *a[100]:   %zu\n", sizeof(a));

   float (*b)[100];
   printf("float (*b)[100]: %zu\n", sizeof(b));
   printf("*b:              %zu\n", sizeof(*b));

   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
float:           4
pointer:         8
float* a[100]:   800       // a is an array of 100 float pointers.
float (*b)[100]: 8         // b is a pointer to an array of 100 floats.
*b:              400
```

---

Note that there's a special case in C where a `[]` does not declare an array, but a pointer. When declaring a function parameter:

```
void f(float *a[], size_t n) {
   // ...
}
```

The `[]` is treated as a pointer declaration, so it's equivalent to:

```
void f(float **a, size_t n) { // ...
```

Since an array decays to a pointer to its first element when passing it as an argument to a function, the function can accept arrays:

```
int main() {
   int n = 100;
   float *a[n];
   // ... Initialize the array here ...
   f(a, n);
   return 0;
}
```

This is a quirk of the C language.

Comment: `float *a[100];` is a very different thing from `float *a[];`, though.

Comment: From lines like "But a[] doesn't have any elements" in the question, it is clear that the lack of a number between the brackets is a deliberate part of the question (regardless of whether it may be based on some other misunderstanding or misreading).

Comment: @user2357112, ok, adjusted.

Comment: It would be good to cover a function parameter of that type, since I suspect that's where the OP saw it.

Comment: I looked at your score so I assumed you knew. As a function parameter, `float *a[]` is equivalent to `float **a`. Just a quirk of the C language.

Comment: @Nikos C., Thanks

Answer (score 4):

An empty array size can be given if the compiler does not need to know the size of the array.

This is the case in two situations:

- `extern` declarations
- function argument types

**Example 1:**

```
extern float *a[];
```

Using the line above you tell the C compiler that there is an array of `float *` elements named `a` in some C file.

**Example 2:**

```
void someFunction(float *a[])
```

Using that line you specify that the argument type is an array of `float *` elements.

Both will work because the compiler does not need to know the size of an array to access it. The compiler only needs to know the size to reserve memory for the array.

In both cases (`extern` and function argument) you will only reference to an existing array (that already occupies memory). Therefore no memory needs to be reserved and the compiler does not need to know the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
float *a[];
```

is an *incomplete* declaration of an array of pointers to `float` since it has no size.  At some point there also needs to be a defining declaration that specifies the number of elements, either explicitly or using an initializer:

```
float *a[];
...
float *a[N];
```

or

```
float *a[];
...
float *a[] = {&a, &b, &c, ...};  // where a, b, c, ..., are objects of type float
```

As a member of a `struct` type, such as

```
struct foo {
  int something;
  int something_else;
  float *a[];
};
```

it's a *flexible array member* - if you just declare an instance of `struct foo` like

```
struct foo bar;
```

then it isn't part of the object (you can't acess `bar.a[i]`).  However, if you allocate the object dynamically, you can specify extra space for the array:

```
struct foo *p = malloc( sizeof *p + sizeof *(p->a) * N );
```

which is equivalent to defining the struct type as

```
struct foo { 
  int something;
  int something_else;
  float *a[N];
};
```